# Selecting a single element in D3 .join

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have the following code which creates a series of points with mouseover and mouseout functions. However, I cannot figure out how to reference a single "point" instance - using the variable point selects all of them:

```
settings.g.selectAll("node")
            .data(positions)
            .join(
                enter => {
                    let point=enter.append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
                    .attr("cy", d => d.y)           
                    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
                    .on('mouseover', (d)=> {
                        pointMouseOver(d)
                        point.attr("stroke-opacity", 1) //THIS SELECTS ALL POINTS, NOT JUST 1
                    })
                    .on('mouseout',  (d)=>pointMouseOut(d))
                    
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `point` variable is the **enter** selection, which in your case contains several elements.

To get the selected element use `this` or, since you have an arrow function:

```
.on('mouseover', (d, i, n)=> {
    d3.select(n[i]).attr("stroke-opacity", 1) 
})
```

In recent versions of D3 you can use `event.currentTarget` in the listener: `.on('mouseover', (event, d) => { ... })`.